# Hyper-V Host OS Compatibility

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have 2 unclustered Hyper-V Hosts:

- HV01 (Windows Server 2012)     Dell PowerEdge R720
- HV02 (Windows Server 2012 R2)  Dell PowerEdge R730

I want to upgrade both hosts to Windows Server 2016, and my plan is to move all the machines off HV01 onto HV02 via Live Migration (tested and works fine), and then upgrade HV01 via clean install.

My question is will I then be able to use live migration (without clustering) to move from HV02 back to HV01 (Now running Server 2016)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest thing I would worry about would be the differences in CPU features.  If the CPU In your R730 has more features, you might not be able to live-migrate it back unless you have the CPU compatibility option set for the VM.

If you can migrate back and forth between the two right now without problems, then you should be fine.  So you could bring up a test VM and migrated it back and for to verify CPUs are compatible enough.

But migrating from 2012r2 to 2016 should be fine.  Going from 2016 back to 2012r2 should also be fine as long as don't upgrade to the 2016+ configuration file version.

Comment: Right now I can only go forwards (I.e. from 2012 host to 2012 R2 host, not the other way around), this is due to incompatibility between the R2 and non-R2 versions i think

Comment: oh, I didn't notice one was 2012, I thought both were  2012R2.